# How to change color of a paginated datatable in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I managed to implement a paginated datatable in my flutter application, but now it display in a greyish color which i dont want. I want to appear white and the column headings in black color together with rows.How can i change the color of the datatable to white?

I already tried using the color property and it is not supported in paginated datatable. I also tried wrapping the datatable with a container and making the container white.

I expect the datatable(Recent Sessions) to be white in color.[image]

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem like yours, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the PaginatedDataTable by changing the Card color to suit your needs.

Comment: The PaginatedDatatable is not on a card4

Comment: this is not found on class paginatedDataTable

Answer (score 1):

this will solve your issue ..

```
Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context)
            .copyWith(cardColor: Color(0xff232d37), dividerColor: Colors.green),
        child: ListView(
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the `PaginatedDataTable` color in your `ThemeData`:

```
ThemeData(
  cardTheme: CardTheme(
    surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
  ),
);
```