# change color of paginated datatable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, flutter-layout, flutter-web

i look to change the color of paginated datatable  using flutter ,

i use dark themes and paginated datatable take that color , also i read from the flutter web site [enter link description here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PaginatedDataTable/PaginatedDataTable.html)

to use this CardTheme,  but how to use it ..
this my simple code for paginated datatable  ..

```
 class DataTableDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("tesat");

    MySource mySource = new MySource(
      // ["test1##test2", "test3##test4", "test5##test6", "test7##test8"],
      //  ["test1##test2", "test3##test4", "test5##test6", "test7##test8"]
      test2,
      test3,
    );

    return Container(
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   title: Text('Data Tables'),
      // ),
      //backgroundColor: Color(0xff232d37),
      color: Color(0xff232d37),
      child: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
        children: [
          PaginatedDataTable(
            //header: Text('Header Text'),
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            columns: [
              DataColumn(label: Text('Header A')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Header B')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Header C')),
            ],
            //source: _DataSource(context),
            source: mySource,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MySource extends DataTableSource {
  List<String> value;
  List<String> test1;
  String a;
  String b;
  MySource(this.value, this.test1) {
    print(value);
  }

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    // TODO: implement getRow
    // print('test');
    //test1 = value[index].split("");
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      //color: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.blue),
      index: index,
      cells: [
        DataCell(Text(value[index].toString())),
        DataCell(Text(test1[index].toString())),
        DataCell(
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print((value[index]));
            },
            child: Text("Click"),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement isRowCountApproximate
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  // TODO: implement rowCount
  int get rowCount => value.length;

  @override
  // TODO: implement selectedRowCount
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

but now i got this [image]

i need to set color as the       `color: Color(0xff232d37),`
any help is apricated >>

regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change color of a paginated datatable in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062661/how-to-change-color-of-a-paginated-datatable-in-flutter)

Answer (score 8):

found it ,

```
Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context)
            .copyWith(cardColor: Color(0xff232d37), dividerColor: Colors.green),
        child: ListView(
```

this solve my issue

regards